# Проблема в конвертировании WPF приложения в UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, uwp, windows-10

Приложение создавалось для всех версий windows (wpf-приложение), но затем появилась надобность в загрузке в Windows Store. Создал проект UWP и начал переносить код, подключил пространство имён (в данном случает using system.io и system.net), но стали появляться ошибки, связанные с пространством имён. Выяснил, что надо найти эквивалентные имена, но таковых не нашёл. Существует способ конвертировать с помощью набора технологий Desktop Bridge, но пока он тоже мне не понятен. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и использовал данную технологию, прошу уделить пару минут.

Comment: Всё скопом перенести невозможно, в конце-концов, у вас под телефоном просто нет доступа к файловой системе. Задавайте вопросы о функциональности по кускам.

Comment: Задачу конвертирования нужно разделить на части: 1) UI (т.е. `View`), есть расхождение с контролами, нужно предусмотреть работу с разными размерами окна и ориентацией, чего нет в WPF; 2) работа с файлами и проч. тоже нужно переделывать заново.